# PHP Multidimensional Array Extract Specific Values Based Upon Key

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an anchor link by extracting specific array values based upon based upon the key. I've tried using a foreach loop inside of a for loop, however that doesn't seem to work.

Based upon the below multidimensional array how can I loop through each subarray to create individual anchor links, such as:

Example:

```
    /* Array Example */

    array(3) {
          [0]=>
              array(2) {
                ["@attributes"]=>
                    array(1) { 
                        ["id"] => string(1) "2"
                    }
                ["name"]=> string(10) "Mark"
              }
          [1]=>
              array(2) {
                ["@attributes"]=>
                    array(1) {
                      ["id"]=> string(1) "4"
                    }
                ["name"]=> string(8) "John" 
              }
          [2]=>
              array(2) {
                ["@attributes"]=>
                    array(1) {
                      ["id"]=> string(1) "5"
                    }
                ["name"]=> string(10) "Suzy"
              }

    /* Desired Output */

    <a href="example.com?id=2&name=mark"> Mark </a>
    <a href="example.com?id=4&name=john"> John </a>
    <a href="example.com?id=5&name=mark"> Suzy </a>
```

Comment: It is SimpleXML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the array you posted is the content of a variable called $users. You can walk through it by doing

```
foreach ($users as $usr)
{
  $usr['@attributes']['id'];
  $usr['name'];
}
```

This way, you can go through every node without worrying about the indexes.

You may output the link on each foreach iteration in several ways. A complete example (which allows to use HTML without escaping every special character) could be:

```
<?php
foreach ($users as $usr)
{ ?>
  <a href="example.com?id=<?php echo $usr['@attributes']['id']; ?>&name=<?php echo $usr['name']; ?>"><?php echo $usr['name']; ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

While it looks complex, with a lot of PHP opening and closing tags, it makes it easier on the markup with almost no performance penalty

Comment: This is perfect... I don't know why but I was way over complicating this... thank you for the clear answer... the only update I would  add to it is that according to my array example, the `name` node isn't part of the `@attributes` array so it would just be  `usr['name'];`... That's a simple fix, either way I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either ways: ($array is your array)

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name');
$ids = array_map(function($ele){return $ele['@attributes']['id'];}, $array);
```