# Looping through a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, api

I'm trying to learn php and talk to an API to retrieve info for my Destiny 2 clan. I've retrieved all the info that I needed and build a new array with the following format:

```
Array
(
    [displayname] => Senaxx
    [membershipId] => 4611686018428643772
    [characterdetails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2305843009260824684] => Array
                        (
                            [characterlevel] => 30
                            [light] => 384
                            [datelastplayed] => 2018-08-19T13:23:27Z
                            [minutesplayed] => 14901
                            [racehash] => 898834093
                            [genderhash] => 3111576190
                            [emblempath] => /common/destiny2_content/icons/2b6160e0f21e748cd996b404771a850c.jpg
                            [emblemhash] => 10493725
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2305843009260824685] => Array
                        (
                            [characterlevel] => 30
                            [light] => 394
                            [datelastplayed] => 2018-08-18T20:47:09Z
                            [minutesplayed] => 9647
                            [racehash] => 2803282938
                            [genderhash] => 3111576190
                            [emblempath] => /common/destiny2_content/icons/dcfe74b7a343dd28bd45eee4ea59a1f7.jpg
                            [emblemhash] => 3860733295
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2305843009260824686] => Array
                        (
                            [characterlevel] => 30
                            [light] => 394
                            [datelastplayed] => 2018-08-26T00:15:50Z
                            [minutesplayed] => 1802
                            [racehash] => 2803282938
                            [genderhash] => 3111576190
                            [emblempath] => /common/destiny2_content/icons/dcfe74b7a343dd28bd45eee4ea59a1f7.jpg
                            [emblemhash] => 3860733295
                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [displayname] => base1981
    [membershipId] => 4611686018433367605
    [characterdetails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [2305843009265162076] => Array
                        (
                            [characterlevel] => 30
                            [light] => 358
                            [datelastplayed] => 2018-08-15T11:58:46Z
                            [minutesplayed] => 13732
                            [racehash] => 2803282938
                            [genderhash] => 3111576190
                            [emblempath] => /common/destiny2_content/icons/9d512efea06e54c1768d434e53510092.jpg
                            [emblemhash] => 1291068173
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2305843009265162077] => Array
                        (
                            [characterlevel] => 1
                            [light] => 100
                            [datelastplayed] => 2017-09-06T14:25:35Z
                            [minutesplayed] => 0
                            [racehash] => 898834093
                            [genderhash] => 2204441813
                            [emblempath] => /common/destiny2_content/icons/911791e90f955fc637398ea88aba74b7.jpg
                            [emblemhash] => 1907674137
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2305843009265162078] => Array
                        (
                            [characterlevel] => 30
                            [light] => 350
                            [datelastplayed] => 2018-05-27T12:07:38Z
                            [minutesplayed] => 1658
                            [racehash] => 3887404748
                            [genderhash] => 3111576190
                            [emblempath] => /common/destiny2_content/icons/da0d265bb9e4473c97ba56dc7602ca73.jpg
                            [emblemhash] => 3941202506
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

These are only 2 player arrays. My whole code has 8. But for this example I think 2 of them will suffice.

My goal is to loop trough the array and retreive all the player info for each displayname.

So i started with which works perfectly:

```
foreach($claninfo as $clanmember)
{
 echo $clanmember['membershipId']; 
}
```

Only grabbing the characterdetails doesn't work for me sadly enough. 
The problem for mee seems that there is an extra characterId with an unknown number.

```
foreach($claninfo as $clanmember)
{
 echo $clanmember['membershipId']; 
    foreach($claninfo->characterdetails as $characterdetails)
    {
      echo $characterdetails-> light;
    } 
}
```

Ultimate goal is to have a table with some of the info in it:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Displayname</td>
<td>Playtime</td>
<td>Character 1</td>
<td>Character 2</td>
<td>Character 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Senaxx</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>light 384</td>
<td>light 394</td>
<td>light 394</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Base1981</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>light 358</td>
<td>light 100</td>
<td>light&nbsp;350</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multidimensional Array Extract Specific Values Based Upon Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011250/php-multidimensional-array-extract-specific-values-based-upon-key)

Comment: You may find exactly what you're looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011250/php-multidimensional-array-extract-specific-values-based-upon-key/

Comment: Hello Javier, i've looked at your answer, but don't know how to apply it to my situration.

Comment: Do you get output of `echo $clanmember['membershipId'];`?

Comment: @KetanYekale yes. This works perfectly. For each user I get the membershipId

Comment: So please check my solution it Shold work and even jh1711's.

Comment: Please consider approving the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associative array key for till the light is: 
**$claninfo[<some key or index>]['characterdetails'][<Array Index>][<character id>]['light']**

So to access **light** you need to use **foreach** 3 times:

1. To get clanmember from claninfo
2. To iterate $clanmember['characterdetails']
3. To get rid of character id

   ```
   foreach($claninfo as $clanmember)
   {
       echo $clanmember['membershipId']; 


      foreach($clanmember['characterdetails'] as $characterArray)
       {

          foreach($characterArray as $characterid => $characterdetails)
          { // You can access $characterid in this block
              echo $characterdetails['light'];
          } 
       } 
   }
   ```

Comment: Your answer pushed me in the right direction, thanks. My final code is working now. I've marked your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

characterdetails is an array and not an object.

You can loop through the array using the following code

```
foreach($claninfo as $clanmember)
{
    echo $clanmember['membershipId']; 

    foreach($claninfo['characterdetails'] as $characterdetails)
    {
        echo $characterdetails['light'];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I've tried this but this doesn't return anything sadly enough.  Because there is another array in the characterdetails array with the character id's.

Comment: Apologies as I missed it, you can refer to @jh1711 answer, that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are 3 different problems with your code. You are working on arrays, you should not use object notation (->) at all. You use the wrong array in your inner foreach. Third, and this is probably your real question, you need a way to access a key that you don't know (unknown id). That last one can be circumvented for example with `array_values` [(manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). All together:

```
foreach($claninfo as $clanmember)
{
  echo $clanmember['membershipId']; 
  foreach($clanmember['characterdetails'] as $characterdetails) 
  {
    echo array_values($characterdetails)[0]['light'];
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this helped me to analyse the problem and understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was:

```
foreach($claninfo as $clanmember)
{
    echo '<br><b>' . $clanmember['displayname'] . '</b><br>' ; 

  foreach($clanmember['characterdetails'] as $characterArray)
  {
    $characterId = $characterArray['characterId'];
    $characterlight = $characterArray['light'];
    $characterlevel = $characterArray['characterlevel'];
    $characterlastplayed = $characterArray['datelastplayed'];
    $characterminutesplayed = $characterArray['minutesplayed'];
    $characterracehash = $characterArray['racehash'];
    $charactergenderhash = $characterArray['genderhash'];
    $characteremblempath = $characterArray['emblempath'];
    $characteremblemhash = $characterArray['emblemhash'];

    echo 'CharacterId: ' . ($characterId) . '<br>';
    echo 'Light: ' . ($characterlight) . '<br>';
    echo 'level: ' . ($characterlevel) . '<br>';
    echo 'Last Played: ' . ($characterlastplayed) . '<br>';
    echo 'Minutes Played: ' . ($characterminutesplayed) . '<br>';
    echo 'RaceHash: ' . ($characterracehash) . '<br>';
    echo 'GenderHash: ' . ($charactergenderhash) . '<br>';
    echo 'Emblempath: ' . ($characteremblempath) . '<br>';
    echo 'Emblemhash: ' . ($characteremblemhash) . '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
  } 
}
```